# SharePoint Designer 2010 - Set Variable [Today]-x Days

Tags: sharepoint, designer

I'm about to create a Workflow in SharePoint 2010 Designer. I created a Variable calling "DateToday". I set the variable in the Workflow and click on the button with the "..." on it and choose "Current date".

I now have another variable called "TodayMinus28". I want the current date, minus 28 days. How can I do this? I tried

```
[Today]-28
```

and

```
DateToday-28
```

but nothing seem to work. Both variables are initialized as Date/Time.

Can anybody help me?

Here's a screen of my workflow. "Heute" == "Today", "Wert" == "Value".

http://imageshack.us/a/img689/4048/workflow.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please refer to this answer http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144232/add-days-to-date-in-sharepoint-designer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a DateTime field to [Today] + 5 days using a SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow, this is what I did:

1. Create a Local Variable (ETA Date) of type Number
2. Use a Do Calculation task in the workflow and set:

> > **value**: Workflow Context:Date and Time Last Run (As Double)
> >     **operation**: plus 
> >     **value**: 432000 (number of seconds in 5 days or 60*60*24*5)
> >     **Output to**: Variable: ETA Date
> >
> > Finally, set the value of the respective field of the current item to the ETA Date variable
> >
> > In your case, use the **subtract** operation and the second value is **2419200** (60*60*24*28).

Comment: for Today, instead of using "Workflow Context:Date and Time Last Run" you can just create a local variable and then it is possible to set its date to "Current Date".